# Why does IE11 add absolute positioned element width to container width when translate is applied?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

When implementing a tooltip i use `transform: translate` to position the revealed tooltip content relative to its trigger.

However, in **Internet Explorer 11 a scrollbar appears** when hovering the tooltip trigger, it seems like IE somehow adds the translated width to the containing section width.

Other browsers do not show this behavior. I know that adding `-ms-overflow-x: hidden;` to body "solves" the issue but i want to solve it **without that hack**. any help is appreciated.

Note that i did not include decorative styling to only illustrate the issue.

### [Fiddle](http://jsbin.com/redalogako/1/edit?css,output)

```html
<section class="box">
  <h1>Heading</h1>
  <p>
    A beautiful section, lots of new info.
  </p>
  <span class="tooltip">
    Even more info.
     <span class="tooltip-content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </span>
  </span>
</section>
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #e3e3e3;
}

.box {
    margin: 4em auto 0;
    max-width: 400px;
    position: relative;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 1em;
}

.tooltip {
    cursor: help;
    position: absolute;
    right: 1em;
    top: 1em;
}

.tooltip-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 6px 12px 9px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #696969;
    font-weight: normal;

    transform: translate(-100%, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate(-100%, 0);
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltip-content {
    display: block;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That happens because the popup has no `left` set, which, in IE, makes it render right after the text in the `tooltip` element.

If you update your `tooltip-content` rule like this it will work everywhere.

```
.tooltip-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;                     /*  added  */
  right: 100%;                   /*  added  */
  width: 300px;
  padding: 6px 12px 9px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #696969;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

[Updated jsbin](http://jsbin.com/corizironi/1/edit)

Stack snippet

```css
body {
  background-color: #e3e3e3;
}

.box {
  margin: 4em auto 0;
  max-width: 400px;
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 1em;
}

.tooltip {
  cursor: help;
  position: absolute;
  right: 1em;
  top: 1em;
}

.tooltip-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  right: 100%;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 6px 12px 9px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #696969;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltip-content {
  display: block;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<section class="box">

  <span>Heading</span>

  <p>
    A beautiful section, lots of new info.
  </p>

  <span class="tooltip">
            Even more info.
            <span class="tooltip-content">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
            </span>
  </span>

</section>
```